# Cloudformation : VPC security groups may not be used for a non-VPC launch

Tags: aws-cloudformation

The following is my template with vpc,subnet,securitygroup ,launch configuration and autoscaling. 
I am able to create lauch configuration and autoscaling group, but my autoscaling group does not launch instances. 
**I am facing `VPC security groups may not be used for a non-VPC launch` error.**

```
   {
    "myvpc": {
        "Type": "AWS: : EC2: : VPC",
        "Properties": {
            "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
            "EnableDnsSupport": "true",
            "EnableDnsHostnames": "true",
            "InstanceTenancy": "default"
        }
    },
    "mySubnet": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
        "Properties": {
            "VpcId": {
                "Ref": "myvpc"
            },
            "CidrBlock": "10.0.1.0/24",
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "mysubnet",
                    "Value": "mysubnet"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "ec2Security": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "GroupDescription": "my CloudFormation security group",
            "VpcId": {
                "Ref": "myvpc"
            },
            "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "FromPort": "-1",
                    "ToPort": "-1",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                }
            ],
            "SecurityGroupEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "FromPort": "-1",
                    "ToPort": "-1",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "WebServerGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "AvailabilityZones": [
                {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "mySubnet",
                        "AvailabilityZone"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "LaunchConfigurationName": {
                "Ref": "WebServerLaunchConfig"
            },
            "MinSize": "1",
            "MaxSize": "10",
            "DesiredCapacity": {
                "Ref": "DesiredInstances"
            }
        }
    },
    "WebServerLaunchConfig": {
        "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
        "Properties": {
            "ImageId": "ami-xxxxx",
            "InstanceType": {
                "Ref": "InstanceType"
            },
            "KeyName": "xxxxxxxx",
            "SecurityGroups": [
                {
                    "Ref": "ec2Security"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to launch more than one instance in different az in a VPC using Cloudformation.

What I am doing wrong here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The VPC itself is missing in this template:

```
"VpcId" : {"Ref" : "myvpc"},
```

This code means that you should have vpc called "myvpc" created in this template. Just like "ec2Security" or "mySubnet".
If you don;t want new VPC to be created, specify your actual VpcId instead of reference.

For example:

```
"VpcId" : "vpc-a6a673c1"
```

More details regarding how to specify VpcId properly are here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html#cfn-ec2-securitygroup-vpcid

Comment: I have added the code , but I am still facing the same error.